# Deleteing record from MySQL Database after 1 Week

Tags: php, mysql, html, phpmyadmin

I want to know how to delete records from a MySQL Database after 1 week

This is the code I have for inserting the record and date of when it was added

```sql
INSERT INTO moviesdone VALUES ('" . $id2 . "', NOW())
```

Where $id is the name of what I am insterting and wanting to delete after 1 week.

I would also like to do this automatically, which I can set up from in phpMyAdmin

So, I only need to know: How do I write the date correctly (if needed) and how do I delete the record one week later?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run this code at regular intervals, for example once per day:

```
DELETE FROM moviesdone 
WHERE datetimecol < NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

You can use the  [event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/events.html).

Comment: That will not do it automatically

Comment: @MarkByers: yes there is, you can use an event

Comment: @MarkByers: you just wrote a delete query, he wants to know how to run a delete query automatically, I think that is very different

Comment: @nico And i am also using phpMyAdmin and creating the event, i just needed to know, what i need to execute to do it

MarkByers, Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you are using MySQL 5.1.6 or greater you can use [`CREATE EVENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html)

Something like

```
CREATE EVENT del_entries
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
DO
   DELETE FROM table WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), creation_date) >= 7;
```

Comment: good point, although running it once a day on a normal-sized table won't really make a difference.